# New Pandas file show indexes form old pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have created new pandas file from old pandas file based on some conditions. The problem is that indexes in new pandas file are not from 0 to size, indexes are just taken from old pandas.
What am I doing wrong?

[image]

This is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from collections import Counter
import math

df_OnlineRetail = pd.read_csv("OnlineRetailNEW.csv")
#print(df_OnlineRetail.head())
df_size = df_OnlineRetail.shape[0]
#print("No of rows:", df_size)

def get_frequency():

    customer_list = df_OnlineRetail['CustomerID'].tolist()
    no_of_purchases = Counter(customer_list)

    customers = []
    purchases = []

    for key, value in no_of_purchases.items():

        customers.append(key)   
        purchases.append(value)

    frequency_dict = {'CustomerID':customers,
                      'Purchases':purchases}

    df_frequency = pd.DataFrame(frequency_dict)
    df_frequency = df_frequency.reset_index(drop=True)

    print(df_frequency.sort_values(by="Purchases", ascending = False))

Frequency = get_frequency()
```

Comment: You are doing nothing wrong, you are sorting the dataframe, this will not change the index. If you want to have the sorted version with index from 0 to ... , then just use `df.reindex()`  https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html

Comment: What is the content of the file? Can't you just do `pandas.read_csv()` and do the counting of the frequency in pandas?

Comment: I need it in this way

Answer (score 0):

Your new dataframe appears to be sorted in decreasing order by `Purchases`. The original dataframe it was modified from apparently was not. Hence the indices (which will remain as in the original dataframe unless you [reindex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) `df.reindex()`) are now no longer in ascending order.

Comment: How can I fix that, so that  my indexes starts from 1 ,  and to go 2,3,4,5...
I tried with `reindex()` but nothing happens.

Comment: @Aleksandar can you post your input, output, and expected output as text please?